# Json parse #text object

Tags: json, parsing

I'm trying to traverse a JSON array to reach the URL for `size:large`. The `#text` attribute has me confused as I can't include it in my dot notation. I can get to the `size=large` with this:

```
json.track.album.image[2].size
```

but `json.track.album.image[2].#text` won't work.

Here is a snippet of the JSON data:

```
{"track":{"id":"1019817","name":"Believe","mbid":"13194c93-89c6-4ab4-aaf2-     15db5d73b74e","url":"http:\/\/www.last.fm\/music\/Cher\/_\/Believe","duration":"222000","streamable":{"#text":"1","fulltrack":"0"},"listeners":"287271","playcount":"1206650","artist":{"name":"Cher","mbid":"bfcc6d75-a6a5-4bc6-8282-47aec8531818","url":"http:\/\/www.last.fm\/music\/Cher"},"album":{"artist":"Cher","title":"The Very Best of Cher","mbid":"5df00011-6e57-4837-99ae-61f398481db5","url":"http:\/\/www.last.fm\/music\/Cher\/The+Very+Best+of+Cher","image":[{"#text":"http:\/\/userserve-ak.last.fm\/serve\/64s\/71997588.png","size":"small"},{"#text":"http:\/\/userserve-ak.last.fm\/serve\/126\/71997588.png","size":"medium"},{"#text":"http:\/\/userserve-ak.last.fm\/serve\/174s\/71997588.png","size":"large"},{"#text":"http:\/\/userserve-ak.last.fm\/serve\/300x300\/71997588.png","size":"extralarge"}],
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the leading `#`, you have to use the `[]` syntax instead:

```
json.track.album.image[2]['#text']
```

This allows you to specify the key as a string, so special characters are permitted.